# Selection of rows using multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, delete-row

I'd like to delete certain rows from a dataframe, by using multiple boolean selection criteria. Here's my test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(0,10,2), 'b':range(0,1000,200)})
df['c'] = 10*df.b
df
```

[image]

I'm able to select the rows I wish to delete, using these separate commands:

```
df1 = df.ix[df.c>5000]
df2 = df1.ix[df1.b<800]
df2
```

leaving me with df2 comprising of a single row:

[image]

I would love to be able to select the row using one line which might look something like this:

```
df2 = (df.ix[df.c>5000]) & (df.ix[df1.b<800])
df2
```

but that doesn't work. Finally, of course I would like to turn this into a deletion command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a selection, based on the condition that you are trying to apply in your description, try using boolean indexing this:

```
>> condition = (df.c > 5000) & (df.b < 800)
>> df2 = df[condition]
```

and in order to delete, using the same condition, you can do it like this:

```
>> df.drop(df[condition].index.tolist())
```

This will return a `pd.core.frame.DataFrame`, you will want to assign here or use `inplace` flag like this:

```
>> df.drop(df[condition].index.tolist(), inplace=True)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great first half of your answer - the selection works in a single line! But the second bit of your answer depends on manual intervention (after first knowing that row c has a value of 6000 - actually I would need to write "== 6000").

Comment: So, would you rather be able to delete the row by using a condition, same as when selecting it?

Comment: I think you just need to negate: `df = df[~((df.c > 5000) & (df.b < 800))]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete drop the row, rather than keep it, you can just invert your boolean vector with the `~` operator.

```
df2 = df[~((df.c > 5000) & (df.b < 800))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the indices you want to remove by

```
indices = df[(df.c > 5000) & (df.b < 800)].index
```

and remove them like (inplace):

```
df.drop(indices, inplace=True)
```

If you also want to reset the index, then do

```
df = df.drop(indices).reset_index(drop=True)
```